Installed requirements cannot be found in heroku
Hello everyone im trying to deploy a small monorepo app with the ui and the api on the same project. I want to deploy on heroku solely through the git integration and not heroku cli or something else. I use a package.json in my root folder which is the following.
{
"name": "app",
"version": "1.0.0",
"engines": {
    "node": "18.17.0",
    "npm": "10.7.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "cd api && flask run",
    "install-client": "cd ui && npm install && ng build && cd ..",
    "install-server": "cd api && curl -sSL https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && python get-pip.py && python -m pip install -r requirements.txt && python -m pip install flask && export PATH=\"/app/.local/bin:$PATH\" && cd ..",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm cache clean --force && npm run install-client && npm run install-server"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.7",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular":"17.3.7"
}

}
I get and arror when running the start script with flask
2024-05-12T10:14:11.608272+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: flask: not found

At first I did not had the export path in the install-server script but also after adding the error persits (I added it because I saw in the logs that the installed dependencies from required.txt are not on path). I also tried to use virtual environments for python but the same error happened when I added them. Also I tried python3 instead of python in the scripts. Not sure what else can I check and all relevant questions here do not use the package.json with this project structure. Any ideas?
requirements.txt:
el-core-news-lg @ https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/el_core_news_lg-3.7.0/el_core_news_lg-3.7.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=810efefee1419e204499bb0e2524d727fd7bd748354d9c7648734f698fc49bc9
en-core-web-lg @ https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_lg-3.7.1/en_core_web_lg-3.7.1-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=ab70aeb6172cde82508f7739f35ebc9918a3d07debeed637403c8f794ba3d3dc
Flask==3.0.2
Flask-Cors==4.0.0
networkx==3.2.1
pandas==2.2.0
spacy==3.7.4
spacy-legacy==3.0.12
spacy-loggers==1.0.5
tqdm==4.66.1
nltk==3.8.1
emoji==1.7.0
textblob==0.18.0.post0

Heroku build logs:
       Running heroku-postbuild
       
       > app@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild
       > npm run install-server
       
       
       > app@1.0.0 install-server
       > cd api && curl -sSL https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && python get-pip.py && python -m pip install -r requirements.txt && python -m pip install flask && export PATH="/app/.local/bin:$PATH" && cd ..
       
       Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
       Collecting pip
         Downloading pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
       Collecting setuptools
         Downloading setuptools-69.5.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.2 kB)
       Collecting wheel
         Downloading wheel-0.43.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
       Downloading pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.1/2.1 MB 40.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading setuptools-69.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (894 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 894.6/894.6 kB 55.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading wheel-0.43.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 65.8/65.8 kB 8.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools, pip
  WARNING: The script wheel is installed in '/app/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts pip, pip3 and pip3.10 are installed in '/app/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
       Successfully installed pip-24.0 setuptools-69.5.1 wheel-0.43.0
       Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
       Collecting el-core-news-lg@ https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/el_core_news_lg-3.7.0/el_core_news_lg-3.7.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=810efefee1419e204499bb0e2524d727fd7bd748354d9c7648734f698fc49bc9 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
         Downloading https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/el_core_news_lg-3.7.0/el_core_news_lg-3.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (568.6 MB)
            ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 568.6/568.6 MB 1.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Collecting en-core-web-lg@ https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_lg-3.7.1/en_core_web_lg-3.7.1-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=ab70aeb6172cde82508f7739f35ebc9918a3d07debeed637403c8f794ba3d3dc (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
         Downloading https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_lg-3.7.1/en_core_web_lg-3.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (587.7 MB)
            ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 587.7/587.7 MB 1.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Collecting Flask==3.0.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
         Downloading flask-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
       Collecting Flask-Cors==4.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
         Downloading Flask_Cors-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.4 kB)
       Collecting networkx==3.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
         Downloading networkx-3.2.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.2 kB)
       Collecting pandas==2.2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
         Downloading pandas-2.2.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (19 kB)
       Collecting spacy==3.7.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading spacy-3.7.4-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (27 kB)
       Collecting spacy-legacy==3.0.12 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
         Downloading spacy_legacy-3.0.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
       Collecting spacy-loggers==1.0.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
         Downloading spacy_loggers-1.0.5-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (23 kB)
       Collecting tqdm==4.66.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
         Downloading tqdm-4.66.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (57 kB)
            ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 57.6/57.6 kB 6.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Collecting nltk==3.8.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
         Downloading nltk-3.8.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
       Collecting emoji==1.7.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
         Downloading emoji-1.7.0.tar.gz (175 kB)
            ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 175.4/175.4 kB 15.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
       Collecting textblob==0.18.0.post0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
         Downloading textblob-0.18.0.post0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.5 kB)
       Collecting Werkzeug>=3.0.0 (from Flask==3.0.2->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
         Downloading werkzeug-3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.7 kB)
       Collecting Jinja2>=3.1.2 (from Flask==3.0.2->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
         Downloading jinja2-3.1.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.6 kB)
       Collecting itsdangerous>=2.1.2 (from Flask==3.0.2->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
         Downloading itsdangerous-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.9 kB)
       Collecting click>=8.1.3 (from Flask==3.0.2->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
         Downloading click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
       Collecting blinker>=1.6.2 (from Flask==3.0.2->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
         Downloading blinker-1.8.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
       Collecting numpy<2,>=1.22.4 (from pandas==2.2.0->-r requirements.txt (line 6))
         Downloading numpy-1.26.4-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (61 kB)
            ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 61.0/61.0 kB 8.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Collecting python-dateutil>=2.8.2 (from pandas==2.2.0->-r requirements.txt (line 6))
         Downloading python_dateutil-2.9.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.4 kB)
       Collecting pytz>=2020.1 (from pandas==2.2.0->-r requirements.txt (line 6))
         Downloading pytz-2024.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (22 kB)
       Collecting tzdata>=2022.7 (from pandas==2.2.0->-r requirements.txt (line 6))
         Downloading tzdata-2024.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
       Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0 (from spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading murmurhash-1.0.10-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (2.0 kB)
       Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2 (from spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading cymem-2.0.8-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (8.4 kB)
       Collecting preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading preshed-3.0.9-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
       Collecting thinc<8.3.0,>=8.2.2 (from spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading thinc-8.2.3-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (15 kB)
       Collecting wasabi<1.2.0,>=0.9.1 (from spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading wasabi-1.1.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (28 kB)
       Collecting srsly<3.0.0,>=2.4.3 (from spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading srsly-2.4.8-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (20 kB)
       Collecting catalogue<2.1.0,>=2.0.6 (from spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading catalogue-2.0.10-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (14 kB)
       Collecting weasel<0.4.0,>=0.1.0 (from spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading weasel-0.3.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.7 kB)
       Collecting typer<0.10.0,>=0.3.0 (from spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading typer-0.9.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (14 kB)
       Collecting smart-open<7.0.0,>=5.2.1 (from spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading smart_open-6.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (21 kB)
       Collecting requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 (from spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
       Collecting pydantic!=1.8,!=1.8.1,<3.0.0,>=1.7.4 (from spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading pydantic-2.7.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (107 kB)
            ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 107.3/107.3 kB 14.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /app/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7)) (69.5.1)
       Collecting packaging>=20.0 (from spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading packaging-24.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
       Collecting langcodes<4.0.0,>=3.2.0 (from spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading langcodes-3.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (29 kB)
       Collecting joblib (from nltk==3.8.1->-r requirements.txt (line 11))
         Downloading joblib-1.4.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.4 kB)
       Collecting regex>=2021.8.3 (from nltk==3.8.1->-r requirements.txt (line 11))
         Downloading regex-2024.5.10-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (40 kB)
            ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 40.9/40.9 kB 5.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0 (from Jinja2>=3.1.2->Flask==3.0.2->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
         Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.5-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
       Collecting language-data>=1.2 (from langcodes<4.0.0,>=3.2.0->spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading language_data-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.3 kB)
       Collecting annotated-types>=0.4.0 (from pydantic!=1.8,!=1.8.1,<3.0.0,>=1.7.4->spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading annotated_types-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (12 kB)
       Collecting pydantic-core==2.18.2 (from pydantic!=1.8,!=1.8.1,<3.0.0,>=1.7.4->spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading pydantic_core-2.18.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (6.5 kB)
       Collecting typing-extensions>=4.6.1 (from pydantic!=1.8,!=1.8.1,<3.0.0,>=1.7.4->spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading typing_extensions-4.11.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
       Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.2->pandas==2.2.0->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (1.16.0)
       Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2 (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading charset_normalizer-3.3.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (33 kB)
       Collecting idna<4,>=2.5 (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading idna-3.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.9 kB)
       Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7)) (1.26.5)
       Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7)) (2020.6.20)
       Collecting blis<0.8.0,>=0.7.8 (from thinc<8.3.0,>=8.2.2->spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading blis-0.7.11-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (7.4 kB)
       Collecting confection<1.0.0,>=0.0.1 (from thinc<8.3.0,>=8.2.2->spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading confection-0.1.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (19 kB)
       Collecting cloudpathlib<0.17.0,>=0.7.0 (from weasel<0.4.0,>=0.1.0->spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading cloudpathlib-0.16.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (14 kB)
       Collecting marisa-trie>=0.7.7 (from language-data>=1.2->langcodes<4.0.0,>=3.2.0->spacy==3.7.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading marisa_trie-1.1.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (8.6 kB)
       Downloading flask-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (101 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 101.3/101.3 kB 16.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading Flask_Cors-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
       Downloading networkx-3.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.6/1.6 MB 51.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading pandas-2.2.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (13.0 MB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 13.0/13.0 MB 115.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading spacy-3.7.4-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (6.6 MB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 6.6/6.6 MB 121.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading spacy_legacy-3.0.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
       Downloading spacy_loggers-1.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
       Downloading tqdm-4.66.1-py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 78.3/78.3 kB 12.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading nltk-3.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.5/1.5 MB 99.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading textblob-0.18.0.post0-py3-none-any.whl (626 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 626.3/626.3 kB 64.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading blinker-1.8.2-py3-none-any.whl (9.5 kB)
       Downloading catalogue-2.0.10-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
       Downloading click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 97.9/97.9 kB 15.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading cymem-2.0.8-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (46 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━��━━━━━ 46.1/46.1 kB 6.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading itsdangerous-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
       Downloading jinja2-3.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 133.3/133.3 kB 20.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading langcodes-3.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (182 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 182.0/182.0 kB 25.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading murmurhash-1.0.10-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (29 kB)
       Downloading numpy-1.26.4-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (18.2 MB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 18.2/18.2 MB 106.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading packaging-24.0-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━��━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 53.5/53.5 kB 7.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading preshed-3.0.9-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (156 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 156.9/156.9 kB 21.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading pydantic-2.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (409 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 409.3/409.3 kB 48.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading pydantic_core-2.18.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (2.1 MB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.1/2.1 MB 105.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading python_dateutil-2.9.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (229 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 229.9/229.9 kB 30.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading pytz-2024.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (505 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 505.5/505.5 kB 46.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading regex-2024.5.10-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (774 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 774.1/774.1 kB 68.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 62.6/62.6 kB 8.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading smart_open-6.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 57.0/57.0 kB 8.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading srsly-2.4.8-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (493 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 493.0/493.0 kB 57.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading thinc-8.2.3-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (922 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 922.3/922.3 kB 82.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading typer-0.9.4-py3-none-any.whl (45 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 46.0/46.0 kB 7.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading tzdata-2024.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (345 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 345.4/345.4 kB 37.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading wasabi-1.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
       Downloading weasel-0.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (50 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 50.1/50.1 kB 7.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading werkzeug-3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 227.3/227.3 kB 32.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading joblib-1.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (301 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 301.8/301.8 kB 39.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading annotated_types-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
       Downloading blis-0.7.11-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (10.2 MB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10.2/10.2 MB 128.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading charset_normalizer-3.3.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (142 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 142.1/142.1 kB 20.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading cloudpathlib-0.16.0-py3-none-any.whl (45 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 45.0/45.0 kB 6.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading confection-0.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
       Downloading idna-3.7-py3-none-any.whl (66 kB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 66.8/66.8 kB 9.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading language_data-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.4 MB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 5.4/5.4 MB 116.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.5-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (25 kB)
       Downloading typing_extensions-4.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
       Downloading marisa_trie-1.1.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.3 MB)
          ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.3/1.3 MB 91.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
       Building wheels for collected packages: emoji
         Building wheel for emoji (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for emoji (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for emoji: filename=emoji-1.7.0-py3-none-any.whl size=171034 sha256=eeef11f45e3b0973de4d98db5a2af88253e631a772543cba0dd08033b0b08232
         Stored in directory: /app/.cache/pip/wheels/31/8a/8c/315c9e5d7773f74b33d5ed33f075b49c6eaeb7cedbb86e2cf8
       Successfully built emoji
       Installing collected packages: pytz, emoji, cymem, wasabi, tzdata, typing-extensions, tqdm, spacy-loggers, spacy-legacy, smart-open, regex, python-dateutil, packaging, numpy, networkx, murmurhash, MarkupSafe, marisa-trie, joblib, itsdangerous, idna, click, charset-normalizer, catalogue, blinker, annotated-types, Werkzeug, typer, srsly, requests, pydantic-core, preshed, pandas, nltk, language-data, Jinja2, cloudpathlib, blis, textblob, pydantic, langcodes, Flask, Flask-Cors, confection, weasel, thinc, spacy, en-core-web-lg, el-core-news-lg
  WARNING: The script tqdm is installed in '/app/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script f2py is installed in '/app/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script normalizer is installed in '/app/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script nltk is installed in '/app/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script flask is installed in '/app/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script weasel is installed in '/app/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script spacy is installed in '/app/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
       Successfully installed Flask-3.0.2 Flask-Cors-4.0.0 Jinja2-3.1.4 MarkupSafe-2.1.5 Werkzeug-3.0.3 annotated-types-0.6.0 blinker-1.8.2 blis-0.7.11 catalogue-2.0.10 charset-normalizer-3.3.2 click-8.1.7 cloudpathlib-0.16.0 confection-0.1.4 cymem-2.0.8 el-core-news-lg-3.7.0 emoji-1.7.0 en-core-web-lg-3.7.1 idna-3.7 itsdangerous-2.2.0 joblib-1.4.2 langcodes-3.4.0 language-data-1.2.0 marisa-trie-1.1.1 murmurhash-1.0.10 networkx-3.2.1 nltk-3.8.1 numpy-1.26.4 packaging-24.0 pandas-2.2.0 preshed-3.0.9 pydantic-2.7.1 pydantic-core-2.18.2 python-dateutil-2.9.0.post0 pytz-2024.1 regex-2024.5.10 requests-2.31.0 smart-open-6.4.0 spacy-3.7.4 spacy-legacy-3.0.12 spacy-loggers-1.0.5 srsly-2.4.8 textblob-0.18.0.post0 thinc-8.2.3 tqdm-4.66.1 typer-0.9.4 typing-extensions-4.11.0 tzdata-2024.1 wasabi-1.1.2 weasel-0.3.4
       Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
       Requirement already satisfied: flask in /app/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (3.0.2)
       Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=3.0.0 in /app/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from flask) (3.0.3)
       Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=3.1.2 in /app/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from flask) (3.1.4)
       Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=2.1.2 in /app/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from flask) (2.2.0)
       Requirement already satisfied: click>=8.1.3 in /app/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from flask) (8.1.7)
       Requirement already satisfied: blinker>=1.6.2 in /app/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from flask) (1.8.2)
       Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /app/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from Jinja2>=3.1.2->flask) (2.1.5)
       
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       
       removed 834 packages, and audited 1 package in 2s
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 44.5M
-----> Launching...
       Released v16 ```


I solved this by moving the requirements.txt the root folder of the project, my project structure is:
   Project
   |   ui
   |   api

and requirements.txt were inside the api folder.
Note that I had the python buildpack in my settings alongside the nodejs buildpack of heroku. Heroku without requirements could not understand what was needed and skipped the required installations. I was explicitly telling it to download pip and install requirements inside the api and after the previous solution I also removed this from the package.json install script of the server and added only angular ones. Meaning:
...
"scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "cd ui && ng serve && cd ..",
        "build": "cd ui && ng build --aot --configuration production && cd ..",
        "test": "echo \"no test..\" && exit 1",
        "lint": "echo \"no lint..\" && exit 1",
        "e2e": "echo \"no e2e...\" && exit 1"
    },
...

In addition I added a Procfile with the following contents
web: gunicorn api.wsgi:app

